# gcloud authentication problem on TTS python script

Tags: python, authentication, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-authentication

I am following this document: https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#client-libraries-install-python

I have followed the instructions.  I get an error when I run the provided Python code ("Create audio data" section).

First Try:

It appears the problem is with authentication.  I authenticated with gcloud init.

```
C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\Scripts\python.exe C:/webDev/pycharm/TTS-Nov-/TTS-Main.py
C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py:66: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 533, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1541901610.961000000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/webDev/pycharm/TTS-Nov-/TTS-Main.py", line 26, in <module>
    response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\texttospeech_v1\gapic\text_to_speech_client.py", line 257, in synthesize_speech
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 139, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 61, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
```

2. Second Try Update:

I ran this 
gcloud auth activate-service-account test-2@tts-alphax-nov.iam.gserviceaccount.com --key-file="C:\webDev\keys\google-cloud\tts-alphax-nov-b101c56c70b7.json" --project=tts-alphax-nov

This resulted in: 
Activated service account credentials for: [test-2@tts-alphax-nov.iam.gserviceaccount.com]
I then ran the python again and this was the error I got.

```
C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\auth\_default.py:66: UserWarning: Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from Google Cloud SDK. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. If your application continues to use end user credentials from Cloud SDK, you might receive a "quota exceeded" or "API not enabled" error. For more information about service accounts, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/
  warnings.warn(_CLOUD_SDK_CREDENTIALS_WARNING)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 59, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 533, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\grpc\_channel.py", line 467, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _Rendezvous(state, None, None, deadline)
grpc._channel._Rendezvous: <_Rendezvous of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/."
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1541903472.332000000","description":"Error received from peer","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1017,"grpc_message":"Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.","grpc_status":7}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/webDev/pycharm/TTS-Nov-/TTS-Main.py", line 26, in <module>
    response = client.synthesize_speech(synthesis_input, voice, audio_config)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\texttospeech_v1\gapic\text_to_speech_client.py", line 257, in synthesize_speech
    request, retry=retry, timeout=timeout, metadata=metadata)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\gapic_v1\method.py", line 139, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 260, in retry_wrapped_func
    on_error=on_error,
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\retry.py", line 177, in retry_target
    return target()
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\timeout.py", line 206, in func_with_timeout
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\webDev\pycharm\TTS-Nov-\lib\site-packages\google\api_core\grpc_helpers.py", line 61, in error_remapped_callable
    six.raise_from(exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc), exc)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 Your application has authenticated using end user credentials from the Google Cloud SDK or Google Cloud Shell which are not supported by the texttospeech.googleapis.com. We recommend that most server applications use service accounts instead. For more information about service accounts and how to use them in your application, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/.
```

Comment: Try this: `set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=path_to_service_credentials.json` in your command prompt shell. Then try the program again.

Comment: I got a slightly different (error)[https://docs.google.com/document/d/1anQLTU361FaBticgBlWDeAHG_41NtHc5cY_uTO6OcAI/edit?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 1):

This error message is usually thrown when the application is not being **authenticated** correctly due to several reasons such as missing files, invalid credential paths, incorrect environment variables assignations, among other causes. Keep in mind that when you set an environment variable value in a session, it is reset every time the session is dropped.

Based on this, I suggest you to validate that the credential file and file path are being correctly assigned (avoiding to include blank characters when setting the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env variable), as well as try to explicitly specify your service account file directly into your code by adding the following `credentials` code to your solution:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('<serviceAccountPath>.json')

texttospeech.TextToSpeechClient(credentials=credentials)
```

Comment: I ran into some problems with this. Python errored out on some of the google modules.  I will try to get the errors posted